# Poco logging 64 bit numbers

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I must be blind because I can't see this one...

I've got a `Poco::Stopwatch` around a chunk of code, and I know I can get the result with `Clock::ClockDiff elapsed() const;` where `ClockDiff` is `Int64`.

I want to log the result using `poco_information_f1("x() took %?? us", diff);`, but I can't find the magic value for `??`. Google suggested `%lld` or `%Ld` was the right specifier, but both showed as `[ERRFMT]`.

Any hints?

Comment: Did you try `%d`?  How about `%s`?

Comment: @wallyk No - I assumed I needed something "special" for 64 bit. `%d` is worth a try, but `%s`?

Comment: I don't know `Poco` and a quick glance of the website did not reveal the type Stopwatch.  It is conceivable it returns a string with complex formatting.

Comment: [Poco::Stopwatch](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Stopwatch.html) returns a [Poco::ClockDiff](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Clock.html#9119) which is a [Poco::Int64](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.html#18312)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`poco_information_f1` is a macro that resolves to passing the arguments to to `Poco::format`, whose documentation is [here](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.html#12509).

So the right modifier is `%?d` which will take any integer type from `short` through to 64-bit int.  You were nearly there with your guess of `%??`  :D

This works because `Poco::format` is not a C-style variadic function; instead it takes extra parameters of type `Poco::Any`, so the function knows exactly what data type the argument was.